Calling transfer function from node server on anchor
Error: AnchorError caused by account: recipient. Error Code: ConstraintMut. Error Number: 2000. Error Message: A mut constraint was violated.

 #![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::system_program;

declare_id!("BwVTNv9QWnp6WqyzUaR5Fmnt5DLJjmtrGVgLY57o3hww");

#[program]
pub mod transfer_sol {
    use super::*;

    pub fn transfer_sol_with_cpi(ctx: Context<TransferSolWithCpi>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Working in transfer_sol_with_cpi function"); // Log message
        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.recipient.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            amount,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferSolWithCpi<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    recipient: SystemAccount<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

this is how I am calling it
const txSignature = await program.methods
    .transferSolWithCpi(new anchor.BN(lamports))
    .accounts({
        payer: adminWallet.publicKey,
        recipient: recipientPubkey,
        system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .rpc();


There is nothing wrong with the code your provided.
I think you might have forgotten to save your file. (ctrl + s)
Also, you might want to update your tests. As per the latest anchor version (0.30.1), you do not need to provide commonly used accounts like the system program.
Calling the instruction as show below shouldn't result in an error
const tx = await program.methods
    .transferSolWithCpi(new anchor.BN(lamports))
    .accounts({
        payer: adminWallet.publicKey,
        recipient: recipientPubkey,
    })
    .rpc();

Else if you have to have all your accounts explicitly included make sure that the naming complies with anchor. Anchor converts your snake_case methods to camelCase and as such, from your code system_program should be renamed to systemProgram
anchor account resolution docs -> https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.30.0#account-resolution

Getting same issue .
One more thing I am testing on local host by running test-validator , is there chance if I am transfer sol from one to other using local (using localhost wallet) so that's why it is not working .

running the tests locally shouldn't be a problem and your code is correct so I don't see where the errors are coming from. Can you try running this on the solana playground
